# Laravel Invoke or render a component directly from a route or controller

Tags: laravel

I have a component

```
class Projects extends Component
{

    public $projects;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->projects = Project::get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.projects');
    }
}
```

and the corresponding `components/projects.blade.php` file containing

```
@dump($projects)
```

I saw somewhere it is possible to return the component view directly from a route. However, none of these works

```
Route::get('projects1', Projects::class); // error

Route::get('projects2', [Projects::class]); // error

Route::get('projects3', [Projects::class, 'render']); // view does not have access to public $projects

Route::get('projects4', [Projects::class, '__construct']); // renders blank

Route::view('projects5', 'components.projects'); // view does not have access to public $projects

Route::get('projects6', fn() => view('components.projects'));  // view does not have access to public $projects

Route::get('projects7', fn() => <<<'blade'
    <x-projects></x-projects>
blade); // component not accessed
```

Any clue?

When `components/projects.blade.php` contains

```
 @dump(get_defined_vars())
```

I see

```
array:5 [▼
  "__path" => "...\storage\framework\views/80c6e39e032dd35edb0d114508f22feaa7951180.php"
  "__data" => array:3 [▶]
  "__env" => Illuminate\View\Factory {#1791 ▶}
  "app" => Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#4 ▶}
  "errors" => Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#1811 ▶}
]
```

`projects` is missing when using

```
Route::view('projects5', 'components.projects');
```

The component class is not active, only the blade file.

When using either

```
return view('components.projects');

return (new Projects)->render();

return app(Projects::class)->render();
```

from a controller, I get the same results.

The only way I can make it act as a component is going via a blade file containing

```
<x-projects></x-projects>
```

In that case, I see, as expected for a component:

```
array:10 [▼
  "__path" => "...\storage\framework\views/80c6e39e032dd35edb0d114508f22feaa7951180.php"
  "__data" => array:8 [▶]
  "__env" => Illuminate\View\Factory {#1793 ▶}
  "app" => Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#4 ▶}
  "errors" => Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#1813 ▶}
  "projects" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1831 ▶}
  "componentName" => "projects"
  "attributes" => Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag {#1820 ▶}
  "slot" => Illuminate\Support\HtmlString {#1823 ▶}
  "__laravel_slots" => array:1 [▶]
]
```

I wish to avoid to use an intermediate file only referencing the component.

Comment: Are you clearing your view and route caches between tests? You should be using `Route::view('projects', 'components.projects');` if you don't have a controller. Second argument of route methods is a controller class and not a component class, which has no facilities for handling requests.

Comment: @miken32 good catch about controller and component classes. but the view does not work, even after clearing caches.

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? I see `$projects` listed as a collection in your output from `dump()` above.

Comment: @miken32, I updated the question to clarify what I mean it does not work.

Comment: "I wish to avoid to use an intermediate file only referencing the component." Better build your own framework. Alternatively, work with what you have, not what you wish for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taylor just showed this new feature at Laracon. It is part of Laravel  release 8.83

```
Route::get('projects', fn() => Blade::renderComponent(new Projects()));
```

https://youtu.be/0Rq-yHAwYjQ?t=20525

[image]

It is this pull request: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40745